# Remove strings between two substrings

Tags: string, vb.net, svg, replace

I have strings from a SVG file which contains image codes like this:

```
<image id="image73" width="100" height="100" xlink:href="unnecsesarrything/>
```

I'm trying to remove sections like this, with this VB code

```
Do Until InStr(text, "<image") = 0
    text = Replace$(text, Mid$(text, InStr(text, "<image"), InStr(text, ">") - InStr(text, "<image") + 10000), "")
Loop
```

This works but doesn't finds the next ">" after the "<image" Which is not what I want.

Comment: If you want to separate the various bits that are separated by spaces, I'd look at using the [split](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualbasic.strings.split?view=net-5.0) command.  If there is a specific bit that you want to extract, then I might would consider using [regular expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/regular-expressions) (regex) instead.  Have a look at both.

Comment: The SVG file is XML.  Use the .Net XML classes to load and manipulated the contents.

Comment: No more old VB6 methods. For InStr use IndexOf. For Mid use Substring.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit to add another example here:

Front-End code to show  html and some  nodes inside it

```
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">

        <svg value="adfsafsaf" id="asfdsaf">
            test 123asdfsaf
            <img src="Images/green.png" alt="green" />
            <img src="Images/red.png" alt="red" />
            asdfsafd asdfsafdsafdsaf
            asdfsaf asdfsafsaf
            <p>
                asdfasfsaf
            </p>
            <img src="Images/blue.png" alt="blue" />
        </svg>

    </form>
</body>
```

Code-behind

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Dim imgs As List(Of String) = GetImagesFromHtmlString(Me.form1.InnerText)

    For Each imgTag As String In imgs
        ' do whatever you want with them
    Next

End Sub

Private Function GetImagesFromHtmlString(ByVal htmlString As String) As List(Of String)
    Dim pattern As String = "<(img)\b[^>]*>"
    Dim rgx As New Regex(pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
    Dim matches As MatchCollection = rgx.Matches(htmlString)

    Dim result As New List(Of String)()

    For i As Integer = 0 To matches.Count - 1
        result.Add(matches(i).Value)
    Next

    Return result
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I couldn't manage to get this work. Don't know why but, the if doesn't answer when I add msgbox to both sides.

Comment: Can you provide an example markup for what you are trying to pull out? Your original post shows ````<image>````

Comment: @KeremÖmerŞahin updated to show another example

Comment: Thank you very much. This one worked perfectly.

Comment: @KeremÖmerŞahin You can't use MsgBox() in a web page.